# Select Datetime into rows of days and column of time for the day

Tags: mysql, select

Is there any ways to `SELECT` all rows of `datetime` from a table into a rows of day and column of time. this table A, records all transaction daily and each day table will store 3 entries. Which means, if the `SELECT` succeed, it will return rows of day and 3 columns of time associated with the day.

table structure, 
id (int), date(datetime), remarks(varchar)

table A

```
id  |     date             |    remarks
--------------------------------
1     2017-01-26 09:14:46     pass
2     2017-01-26 16:08:05     pass
3     2017-01-31 08:46:31     halt
4     2017-01-31 17:22:08     pass
```

`SELECT` output

```
    date       |     time 1   |    time 2
    --------------------------------
   2017-01-26     09:14:46     16:08:05
   2017-01-31     08:46:31     17:22:08
```

cheers.

Comment: I'm a little confused. can you make an example run . just a simulated one

Comment: Your question is not clear what you want to say by "it will return rows of day and 3 columns of time associated with the day." Please be clear and read instructions before posting any question on stackoverflow

Comment: What if there are three days (same date and different times)? It should create three columns? If so, there are two ways to solve it. Dynamic sql OR instead of columns a comma separated values for the times. The last one is easier.